# How to make AltGr temporarily switch keyboard language?

Tags: keyboard, 18.04, language-support, shortcut-keys

I have a keyboard with English and Russian letters. <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> switches language.

I want also the right <kbd>AltGr</kbd> temporarily switch language while this key is pressed.

How to assign this function to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>?

Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can set such option.

You need to install GNOME Tweaks with

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

then launch it and:

1. Click on *Keyboard & Mouse* group
2. In *Keyboard* section click *Additional Layout Options* button
3. In opened window expand *Switching to another layout*
4. Check checkbox named *Right Alt (while pressed)*:

   [image: GNOME Tweaks - set Additional Layout Options]
5. Close *Additional Layout Options* window and exit GNOME Tweaks.

Note: keyboard layout indicator does not react on pressed <kbd>RightAlt</kbd> and constantly shows the first layout name. I reported this as [bug 1779327 to launchpad.net](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1779327).

Comment: I had the exact opposite problem: My alt-gr was switching to another language but I needed it to enter special characters on a Turkish keyboard. The fix was to use `gnome-tweaks` to turn OFF Right alt checkbox.