# 22.04 Switch to another keyboard layout RightAlt (while pressed)

Tags: keyboard-layout, wayland, 22.04

I'm using two keyboard layouts - Eng and CZ. In Gnome Tweaks, there is a great feature to switch keyboard by pressing RightAlt (Keyboard / Additional Layout / Switch to another layout / Right Alt while pressed), which works great on X-Org.

Unfortunatelly, it does not in most applications on Wayland. It works in e.g. system search, gedit, terminal - but does not work in Chrome, Firefox, VS Code, and so on.

Is there any settings to disable this AltGr key for application and let OS to use it for temporary keyboard layout switch?

Comment: Right Alt is probably a bad choice as the shortcut for changing layout, since it's defined by at least the Czech layout as the modifier to access 3rd and 4th level symbols.

Comment: Default keyboard is Eng - so it is not so bad idea. I use it only to write special czech charracters, and it is super easy... I used to use it for years in 16.04, 18.04 and 20.04. In Windows, there is practically same keyboard - called Czech programmers (English with special czech charracters while AltGr pressed)

Comment: I use a similar solution, but with menu key. I found out that in some applications it jumps by one layout and in others by two layouts. It works when I have the alternative layout set twice.

Comment: I'm also struggling with this issue, as it is the standard way to input APL symbols in Linux - the apl xkb symbols are its own language which is used in tandem with the user's natural language. They can then choose whichever layout changing key works best for their setup.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/a/1050716

**BUT!**
In the **Settings->Keyboard->Input Sources**, **the Czech layout has to be first**, then the English one